# Get object out of multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three arrays filled with objects in JavaScript that I've put into a multi-dimensional array in order to get all possible combinations of all three objects to create a set of 'rules'. Then later in the code I want to be able to pull out the properties of these objects, but when I attempt to all I seem to be able to get is the string "[object]" and not the actual object itself.

This is how the array is put together:

```
var allArrays = [settings.serviceLevels, settings.serviceDays, settings.services];
function allPossibleCases(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        return arr[0];
    } else {
        var result = [];
        var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1)); 
        for (var i = 0; i < allCasesOfRest.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                result.push(arr[0][j] + allCasesOfRest[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
var uncheckedRules = allPossibleCases(allArrays);
```

I need to be able to get the properties out of settings.serviceLevels, settings.serviceDays and settings.services - I can find questions that do this with regular arrays but not with objects - is this even possible or have I taken it to a level where I've lost the properties?

Comment: Can you please put your object array?

Comment: It's loaded in from a database using Angular, so not really unfortunately

Comment: One question, you are trying to return in that function an array with only 1 item and that item will be an object with all the properties?

Comment: I just need one item from each - I don't need the full object

Comment: Use a console.log and then copy it from console...

Comment: Can you clarify a bit - showing your code getting called?  Neither allArrays nor allPossibleCases are actually used.  Additionally I'd def recommend trying a functional approach with `.reduce()`, this is a canonical case for that.  It will eliminate all the indices and much of the mental gymnastics.

Comment: Agree with @LukeWilliams and if you are trying to get an object with all properties you can use .extend()

Comment: Added the call - I don't need all the properited, I just need the one to have a string to pass into the rule

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood what you wanted. But here's a recursive function that will store in an array the properties of objects contained in another array :

```
function listProps(object, result) {
    // for each property of the object : 
    for (objectProperty in object) {
        // if it's an object, recursive call : 
        if (typeof object[objectProperty] === 'object') {
            listProps(object[objectProperty], result);
        } else { // otherwise, push it into the result array : 
            result.push(object[objectProperty]);
        }
    }
}

var allArrays = [settings.serviceLevels, settings.serviceDays, settings.services];
var result = [];
listProps(allArrays, result);
```

The `result` array should list every properties from the three objects settings.serviceLevels, settings.serviceDays, settings.services and their children (if they contain any object themselves).